# Node option "host" must be present and be a non-empty string

Tags: nodejs, npm, discord.js

Estoy iniciando un bot de discord y en replit, y al momento de iniciarlo me sale el siguiente error:

/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/node_modules/erela.js/dist/structures/Node.js:25
throw new TypeError('Node option "host" must be present and be a non-empty string.');
^

TypeError: Node option "host" must be present and be a non-empty string.
at check (/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/node_modules/erela.js/dist/structures/Node.js:25:15)
at new Node (/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/node_modules/erela.js/dist/structures/Node.js:68:9)
at new Manager (/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/node_modules/erela.js/dist/structures/Manager.js:82:17)
at new DiscordMusicBot (/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/structures/DiscordMusicBot.js:136:20)
at Object. (/home/runner/Discord-MusicBot/index.js:4:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedo llegar ha tener tu solución.
En el archivo que tienes llamado "botconfig.js" tienes una linea que empieza así:

```
Lavalink: {
    id: "Main",
    host: "",
    port: 80,
    pass: "",
    secure: false,
    retryAmount: 200,
    retryDelay: 40,
},
```

Simplemente te falta rellenar agregando un host de lavalink. En el caso de que no tengas ninguno puedes utilizar un host publico:
[https://lavalink.darrennathanael.com](https://lavalink.darrennathanael.com/SSL/lavalink-with-ssl/)

Es así como te quedaría el código:

```
Lavalink: {
    id: "Main",
    host: "lavalink.oops.wtf",
    port: 443,
    pass: "www.freelavalink.ga",
    secure: true,
    retryAmount: 200,
    retryDelay: 40,
},
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.